# Mongoose Module Unable to connect to the database

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

Currently I'm learning nestjs, and when I'm trying to connect my nestjs to mongodb, I got a problem like this.

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (config: ConfigService) => {
        const uri = util.format(
          `mongodb://%s:%s@%s:%d/%s`,
          config.get('DB_USERNAME'),
          config.get('DB_PASSWORD'),
          config.get('DB_HOST'),
          config.get('DB_PORT'),
          config.get('DB_NAME'),
        )
        console.log(uri)
        return {
          uri,
        }
      },
    }),
    UsersModule
  ],
  controllers: [
    AppController
  ],
  providers: [
    AppService
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

the log of the `uri` is `mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/the-db`

but I always got error

```
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database.
```

or the full log of the program is like this

```
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MongooseModule dependencies initialized +35ms
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
mongodb://username:password@localhost:27017/the-db
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:05 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:08 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (2)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:11 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (3)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:14 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (4)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:17 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (5)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:20 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (6)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:23 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (7)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:26 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (8)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:29 PM   ERROR [MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (9)...
[Nest] 25887  - 11/18/2023, 2:24:30 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Authentication failed.
MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/home/damian/projects/youapp/youapp/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.2.0/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:409:18)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/damian/projects/youapp/youapp/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.2.0/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:239:56)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at processIncomingData (/home/damian/projects/youapp/youapp/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.2.0/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:193:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/damian/projects/youapp/youapp/node_modules/.pnpm/mongodb@6.2.0/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:74:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
```

I got authentication failed in the end, so I try to connect the same credentials with the basic nodejs application, and it was connected properly without any error and I could persist data.

- I've changed the mongoose version and it's nothing but same
- I've changed the localhost to 127.0.0.1 but nothing changed
- I've added `?directConnection=true` to the uri but still nothing changed

can somebody tell me what's going on here?:(

edit:

for your information I'm using

- @nestjs/mongoose: ^10.0.2
- mongoose: ^8.0.1

Comment: Are there any special characters inside your `username` or `password`?

Comment: nope, all lowercase and only alphabet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set `authSource: 'admin'` also in MongoDB URI `mongodb://{{username}}:{{password}}@localhost:27017/{{db_name}}?authSource=admin`

Comment: Ow thank u, from your answer I got the fact about this in the documentation

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/connection-string/#srv-connection-format

Optional. Authentication credentials.
If specified, the client will attempt to authenticate the user to the authSource.
If authSource is unspecified, the client will attempt to authenticate the user to the defaultauthdb.
And if the defaultauthdb is unspecified, to the admin database.